# View com duas ou mais tabelas sem vinculo, com colunas diferente e que precisam ser mescladas

Tags: sql, join, view

Tenho duas tabelas,"PRIMEIRATABELA" com os campos nome, sobrenome, e idade, outra tabela "SEGUNDATABELA" com os campos name, last_name, e age as duas tabelas não possui vinculo mas preciso juntar em uma view sendo que por exemplo  PRIMEIRATABELA.nome e SEGUNDATABELA.name teria que fica em uma mesma coluna na view como VIEWTABELA.nomefinal igualmente com os outros campos. sem view com full outer join resolveria meu problema parcialmente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Como fazer

Você pode fazer usando a função `UNION`, assim unindo os resultados das 2 tabelas, e usando como *subquery*:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT nome as nomefinal, sobrenome, idade FROM primeiratabela)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT name as nomefinal, last_name as sobrenome, age as idade FROM segundatabela)
) tabX
ORDER BY nomefinal
```

---

#### Complementando

Na função `UNION`, você terá que ter os mesmos campos nas *querys*, mesmo que seja `NULL`.

Exemplo: em uma tabelaA tenho o campoX e não tenho o campoY. Já na tabelaB, não tenho o campoX e tenho o campoY.

Posso unir em colunas diferentes:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT campoX, NULL FROM tabelaA)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT NULL, campoY FROM tabelaB)
) tab_aux
```

Ou na mesma coluna, como fiz no seu caso, utilizando ***alias***:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  (SELECT campoX as campoU FROM tabelaA)
UNION ALL
  (SELECT campoY as campoU FROM tabelaB)
) tab_aux
```

---

Mais sobre a função [UNION](https://www.devmedia.com.br/sql-utilizando-o-operador-union-e-union-all/37457).

Comment: Era exatamente disso que estava precisando, Obrigado @rbz !